# Telerik MVC Grid Post Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

How to Post Data From Telerik Grid to The Controller After Modifying or Inserting New Records.
I am Working On MVC3 and Want to Send Data Form View to Controller Throw Ajax using Grid.
The Ajax Call Goes to the Controller but no Data Has Gone. I Have Tried Various Kinds of Parameters but Parameters are Null.  Please Specify Both BachEditing and Single Row Editing. I have Tried Both But I Could not Send Data To The Controller.

Answer (score 0):

All of the demos posted on Telerik's demo site have examples of sending data from the edited/updated Grid to the controller. If you take a look at the following demos you can see that in the controller code there are ActionResult methods for the insert/updated/delete functions where you can grab the code on the server-side:

- [Editing Server-side](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/editingserverside)
- [Editing Ajax](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/editingajax)
- [Batch Editing](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/editingbatch)

All of the examples above happen to use the Razor ViewEngine, but you can easily switch over to the WebForms one by selecting "ASPX" next to "About this example"

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do it, But try naming your parameters the same as your column names. for example:

```
.Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ContactName);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
        })
```

could be cought by

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OrderController( int OrderID, string ContactName, string ShipAddress)
{ //code }
```

Hope that helps